# Get JAXBException with hibernate-jpamodelgen 6.1.5.Final

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpamodelgen

When i install 6.1.5.Final and run maven compile, i got this error.

```
java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException
java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

[image]

I had downgrade to lower version of hibernate and jpamodelgen but problem not be resolved.
My dependency setup.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and try

```
mvn clean package -DskipTest
```

Comment: This (missing) dependency was the issue in my case, thank you.